# iCloud music library won't load on new phone

Tags: icloud, iphone

I got a new phone today, have  enabled Apple Music and iCloud library, but every time it goes to "load library" it just stops and goes to a screen that says I have no music.  This happens whether I toggle iCloud music on and off several times, merge or replace.

I'm on wifi trying to do this btw.

Comment: I've got the some problem... Haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: Probably should contact the apple support. Maybe an issue with your apple id. Only they can fix it on their end.

Comment: There is not such thing as “iCloud music” it’s technically called iTunes. iPhones require you to long into your apple (iCloud, same thing here) account for iTunes, icloud, App Store, and some others. Under your settings make sure you’re logged into your account in the iTunes settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out from iCloud and logging back in. Sometimes Apple Music has issues detecting the Music account.